# What library can I use for SOAP on Android that support certificates?

Tags: android, soap, certificate

I'm looking for a library on Android to consume SOAP service request that also support certificates.

Does ksoap2-android support certificates?

There are also other libraries that I can use?

Comment: You should chck this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440062/ksoap-2-android-with-https

Answer (score 0):

ksoap2 is the best lib for SOAP services i ever saw...Try this one, if ksoap2 doesnt support certs, you're just hopeless :/

regards,