# I have a web service i want to call a particular method of from android device

Tags: java, android, web-services

Hi i have web service [Link](http://www.maxconplus.net/maxcon/IosService.asmx)
i want to call a method `Authenticate User` form `Android` using `POST`. how can i call this method?

Comment: FOA: try link?wsdl to see if you can obtain it. Once you get WSDL, well there are way too much ways to invoke it. (you're going to need a SOAP runtime btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use KSOAP2 Lib to manage SOAP in Android. It uses https for the SOAP url.

you can download via this link [a link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksoap2/)!

for more further detail click [here] ([KSOAP 2 Android with HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440062/ksoap-2-android-with-https))!