# how to consume a wcf service in android (Not a RESTful )

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I am developing an android application. Now my application have to consume an existing .NET WCF Service that is already consumed by many other .Net applications, And I have to use this same wcf service (with out making any modifiaction to it, like making it WCF REST Service). I have only option to use wcf service.
How it can be possible. I'm google to much but find not any solution to my problem...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962104/develop-android-app-using-c-sharp might be one way to go as you might use the .NET framework the way you know it

Answer (score 1):

Check out:
[How to call SOAP web service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-in-android)

Unless you wish to add REST API to your service (which by the way isn't that hard, and shouldn't break existing APIs), you need to talk to WCF in it's native language and that's SOAP XML, which sadly isn't supported out of the box.

Also make sure you have an endpoint on your WCF service configured to basicHttpBinding to make your life easier.
If you can't and it's WSHttpBinding only, check this one:
[how to call https wcf soap from android with WSHttpBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967294/how-to-call-https-wcf-soap-from-android-with-wshttpbinding)

Comment: Thank You JoefGoldstein. I got the track..

Comment: Thank You JoefGoldstein. I got the track, but I'm still facing a problem. like SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:ActionNotSupported' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. 
This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver)
or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  
Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements,
 e.g. Message, Transport, None).' faultactor: 'null' detail: null

Comment: can you please help me to solve the problem? Following error is accured.  Code: s:Sender, Reason: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/WCFLast/ServiceOneTest.svc' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.