# How to use Ksoap2 on ssl (https) connection - Android

Tags: android, ssl, soap, https, ksoap2

I am trying to make a soap connection with ksoap2 library on ssl but not able to make it work. I have tried many solutions which i could able to find on internet but no luck.

If anyone can help me with it would be really appreciated. following is my code :

**Errors**

```
onPreExecute
02-18 10:47:19.722    3876-3898/com.example I/LOGINACTIVITY﹕ doInBackground
02-18 10:47:19.722    3876-3898/com.example I/LOGINACTIVITY﹕ making Soap request ...
02-18 10:47:19.791    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:306)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:197)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:130)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.sendData(HttpTransportSE.java:292)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:184)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.Utils.SoapRequest.makeSoapRequestLogin(SoapRequest.java:47)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.LoginActivity.makeRequest(LoginActivity.java:81)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.LoginActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:147)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.example.LoginActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:142)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-18 10:47:19.792    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:113)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:525)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ ... 24 more
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
02-18 10:47:19.793    3876-3898/com.example W/System.err﹕ ... 30 more
02-18 10:47:19.794    3876-3898/com.example I/LOGINACTIVITY﹕ Result -
02-18 10:47:19.841    3876-3876/com.example I/LOGINACTIVITY﹕ onPostExecute
02-18 10:47:19.841    3876-3876/com.example I/LOGINACTIVITY﹕ Result :
02-18 10:47:19.841    3876-3876/com.example I/LOGINACTIVITY﹕ Incorrect Username and Password !!
```

**Activity**

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "https://myhost.com/";
private final String HOST = "myhost.com";
private final String URL = "https://myhost.com/AndroidWFC/AndroidWS.asmx";
private final String WS_OPS = "/MobileWFC/MobileWS.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "https://myhost.com/AndroidWFC/UserControl";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "UserControl";

/* Only relevant part of activity is included. */

// calling constructor
SoapRequest soapRequest = new SoapRequest(NAMESPACE, URL, HOST, WS_OPS , SOAP_ACTION, METHOD_NAME);

// calling soapRequest method
result = soapRequest.makeSoapRequestLogin(txtUsername.getText().toString(), txtPassword.getText().toString(), txtCode.getText().toString());
```

**SoapRequest class**

```
package com.example.Utils;

import android.util.Log;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpsServiceConnectionSE;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpsTransportSE;

/**
 * Created by Sanjay Kumar on 2/16/2015.
 */
public class SoapRequest {

    private String NAMESPACE = "";
    private String URL = "";
    private String HOST = "";
    private String WS_OPS = "";
    private String SOAP_ACTION = "";
    private String METHOD_NAME = "";

    public SoapRequest(String NAMESPACE, String URL, String HOST, String WS_OPS, String SOAP_ACTION, String METHOD_NAME) {
        this.NAMESPACE = NAMESPACE;
        this.URL = URL;
        this.HOST = HOST;
        this.WS_OPS = WS_OPS;
        this.SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_ACTION;
        this.METHOD_NAME = METHOD_NAME;
    }

    public String makeSoapRequestLogin(String user, String pass, String code) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty(makePropertyInfo("Username", user));
        request.addProperty(makePropertyInfo("Password", pass));
        request.addProperty(makePropertyInfo("userdealer", code));

        String result = "";
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        HttpsTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpsTransportSE(HOST,443,WS_OPS,2000);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        SslRequest.allowAllSSL();

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            result = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public PropertyInfo makePropertyInfo(String propertyInfoName, String propertyInfoValue) {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfo.setName(propertyInfoName);
        propertyInfo.setValue(propertyInfoValue);
        propertyInfo.setType(double.class);
        return propertyInfo;
    }
}
```

**SslRequest Class**

```
package com.example.Utils;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

/**
 * Created by Sanjay Kumar on 2/18/2015.
 */

public class SslRequest implements X509TrustManager {

    private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new
            X509Certificate[]{};

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String
            authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String
            authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return _AcceptedIssuers;
    }

    public static void allowAllSSL() {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }

        });

        SSLContext context = null;
        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new SslRequest()};
        }

        try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Check this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4957359/1881611

Comment: yes, i did infact i have made all code from this answer but it doesn't work for me... and the link is broken.. https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/tree/  i don't find those files which is mentioned in the answer

Comment: You will find code here https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/

Comment: It's working now.. There was some problem with the web service. It has been fixed now so my code is working fine.. Thank you very much for the support.